# Optimized Facebook graph query

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any optimal way of retrieving a list of friends *with* their profile pictures?

I'm getting a list of friends and then querying each `userid` for their profile picture URL.

This seems very inefficient if you're loading a big list of friends 500+ and querying each one of them for the profile picture URL.

If it can't be done through the graph, what's the best way to do this with FQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy:

```
/me/friends?fields=name,picture
```

If you want a photo of a specific size, use this:

```
/me/friends?fields=name,picture.type(SIZE)
```

Where `SIZE` is one of `small`, `normal`, `large` or `square`.

In FQL you can do this with

```
SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())
```